# Compare 2 custom dimensions using filters

Tags: google-analytics

On first sight it seems impossible to compare one custom dimension to another using filters.

Case:
I've got 2 custom dimensions, I want a report where I can see how many of my visitors have CD1 = CD2, generic that is , so no specific cases.
In other words : show me every record where CD1 is exactly the same as CD2.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my answer, I am making the assumption that CD1 and CD2 are session scoped custom dimensions. These really aren't perfect answers to your question, but no other natural way springs to mind. To find how many sessions match this criteria, you could:

1 - Use BigQuery

Not available for free users, but with premium access, you could run simple SQL to list all users `WHERE CD1 = CD2`

2 - Custom Report Then Filter

Using a custom report feature, you would enter both CD1 and CD2 as dimensions, and select sessions as the metric. This would give you a report that may look like:

```
CD1   CD2    Users
---   ---    -----
A     A      100
A     B      200
B     A      100
B     B      200
```

From that, you can see that CD1=CD2 for 300 users.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I need, I know option 2 is possible but it gets quite unreadable in large sets.. I only want the ones that are equal. The question actually is , is it possible to do stuff like in option1.. I think not but to be sure i asked :)